# One out of three Nginx routes ignores upstream server

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have configured three locations for a nginx reverse proxy:

```
    location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.html;
    }


    location /login {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;

            proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    }


    location /app {
            rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 last;
            proxy_pass https://10.11.12.13/1020/;

            proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    }
```

The server listening on port 9080 redirects to the route `/app/{generated subpath}`. The server on IP `10.11.12.13` processes the request on `{generated subpath}`. Therefore I remove the prefix path `/app` with a corresponding rewrite rule, then proxying the request to that server's `/1020` endpoint.

For some reason, the nginx reverse proxy doesn't take the `10.11.12.13` upstream server but tries to find the path locally:

```
8888#8888: *470 open() "/var/www/html/html/createCustomer" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: 10.10.10.10, request: "GET /app/html/createCustomer?tokenId=0xC00FF3 HTTP/1.1", host: "10.10.10.10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `last` I believe you are looking for `break`. From the `rewrite` [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

> last
>
> stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;

The `starts a search for a new location matching the changed URi` is what is happening as you are removing the `/app/` part which then matches the `/` location.

> break
>
> stops processing the current set

Comment: Oh yes, that did the magic. Thank you !!! Now nginx uses that server, still a little bug: It won't use the /1020/ endpoint written into the proxy_pass directive.........

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer to this question? I would then open another question explaining in more detail your other issue as it got lost with the rest of your question.

Comment: All right, [added the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328577/nginx-proxy-pass-omitting-path)