# nginx proxy_pass omitting path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have configured a nginx reverse proxy:

```
location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
}


location /login {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;

        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
}


location /app {
        rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass https://10.11.12.13/1020/;

        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
}
```

The server listening on port 9080 redirects to the route /app/{generated subpath}. The server on IP 10.11.12.13 processes the request on {generated subpath}

Nginx doen't use the full path on the `10.11.12.13` upstream server, omitting the `/1020/` endpoint. What could be the reason for this behaviour ?

Comment: The `rewrite...last` statement appears to prevent any requests being sent to `10.11.12.13`. But, the `/1020/` on the `proxy_pass` statement will be ignored if the URI is rewritten by a `rewrite...break` statement.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to change `last` into `break`, I will update the question. Is that a fundamental problem of `break` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) states:

> When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the `rewrite`
>   directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a
>   request (break) ...  In this case, the URI specified in the directive
>   is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

So, you can either use a `rewrite...break`, for example:

```
location /app {
    rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /1020/$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://10.11.12.13;
    ...
}
```

Or, you can let the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements perform the same transformation, for example:

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass https://10.11.12.13/1020;
    ...
}
```

Note that in this latter case, for correct transformation, both values should end with a `/` or neither end with a `/`.